# How to assign Datatypes for the DropDownList bounded with List of Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, servercontrols

I have a DropDownList bounded with List of Items from the SqlDatasource. The List of Items in the DropDownList are bounded based on the following query

> SELECT COLUMN_NAMES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME
>   = 'RESULT')

**My Requirement:** How to assign Multiple Datatypes for those DropDownList Items i.e. Few indexes in the List of Items shall be grouped as Decimal Datatype and Few Indexes shall be grouped as Varchar , DateTime Dataypes.

I would like to generate Dynamic Web controls based on the Datatype of DDL input and the correspoinding DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged().
    My SQL query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='RESULT' group by DATA_TYPE,COLUMN_NAME
```

Output:

```
COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE  

a            decimal
b            decimal
c            decimal
d            int
e            int
f            varchar
g            varchar
h            varchar
i            varchar
j            varchar
```

If a or b or c are selected from DDL i need to generate dynamic web controls uniquely for Decimal datatype SelectedIndexValue.

How to Proceed?

My aspx code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" Height="221px">
        <span style="font-size: 135%; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold"> Search Functionalities </span>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="column_list_for_filter" DataTextField="All_Columns" DataValueField="All_Columns" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="column_list_for_filter" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT COLUMN_NAME 'All_Columns' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='RESULT'  "></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search Flow Periods" Width="144px" />
        <asp:Table ID="dynamic_filter_table" runat="server" ToolTip="Results">
        </asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

C# code:

```
  protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if(DropDownList5.SelectedIndex.Equals(typeof(Decimal)))
         {
            createdynamiccontrols();
         }
         else if (DropDownList5.SelectedIndex.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
         {
             //Create Unique Web Controls
         }

         else if (DropDownList5.SelectedIndex.Equals(typeof(Char)))
         {
             //Create Unique Web Controls
         }
     }
```

Comment: IMHO you need to concate that 2 columns like this - **SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ' - ' + DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Result'** and then bind it to your dropdownlist. Then in the SelectedIndexChanged event you need to use substring function. Let me know if you have any confusion...

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Could you please help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535042/dropdownlist-with-repeated-data-value-fields-onselected-get-confused-and-chooses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will do object level comparison. Which means it will check if both objects are same or not. In your case `DropDownList5.SelectedIndex` will give `int` object, which you are comparing with `typeof` other object, which will always return false, unless the `typeof` is `int`.

Since you are getting the result with the column names as `COLUMN_NAME` and  `DATA_TYPE`, change your `DropDownList` tag to include these column names. As,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="column_list_for_filter" DataTextField="COLUMN_NAME" DataValueField="DATA_TYPE" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Then you will get the `DataType` of the column in `DropDownList5.SelectedValue`, which is a `string`. Then you can add the controls based on the `DropDownList` selection by comparing `SelectedValue` with the `string` name of the `DataType`. As,

```
protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DropDownList5.SelectedValue == "decimal")
    {
        TextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
    }
    else if(DropDownList5.SelectedValue == "int")
    { 
        Label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
    }
    else if(DropDownList5.SelectedValue == "varchar")
    {
        Button1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Bharadwaj Thanks a lot !!! I am able to create Dynamic Web controls for the selectedvalue of Decimal datatype from DDL. You made my day!!

Comment: @ Bharadwaj : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419467/how-to-retrieve-the-input-values-from-dynamically-generated-textboxes  Could you please help on this too ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your scenario in this way, You need to categorize the column_name values based on datatype, once categorized the selected values should display in unique web controls right ?. If so, try with this line of code in dropdwon selectchange event.

```
SqlConnection con=new Sqlconnenction("Your Connection String");
con.Open();
Sqlcommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from your database",con); // Your two columns
SqlDateReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
  if(dr.GetString(1) == "decimal") // dr.GetString(1) = 'Your Second Column'
  {
    TextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
  }
  else if(dr.GetString(1)=="int")
  {
    Label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
  }
  else if(dr.GetString(1)=="varchar")
  {
    Button1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
  }
}
con.Close();
```

Let me know if i confused you.

Comment: My DDL list of items are already bounded with the Column names i.e Schema information alone from the SqlDataSource. In the Database side we assign datatypes while creating tables. For DDL list of items if a certain indexes are selected it must check for decimal or int or varchar and then new Textboxes or label web controls must be created

Answer (score 0):

Correct Solution :

If **"e"** is chosen from The following DropDownList inputs the value retained in DropDownList is **"e"**

```
COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE  
a            decimal
b            decimal
c            decimal
d            int
e            int
f            varchar
g            varchar  
h            varchar
i            varchar
j            varchar
```

Source: [DropDownList with repeated data value fields OnSelected get confused and chooses the first one why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535042/dropdownlist-with-repeated-data-value-fields-onselected-get-confused-and-chooses)

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="column_list_for_filter">
</asp:DropDownList>                           

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="column_list_for_filter" runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropDownLists();
        }

        else
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList5.SelectedValue))
            {
                if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue.Contains("decimal"))
                {
                    createdynamiccontrols_decimal();
                }

                else if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue.Contains("varchar"))
                {
                    createdynamiccontrols_varchar();
                }
                else if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue.Contains("datetime"))
                {
                    create_cntrls();
                }

                else if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue.Contains("int"))
                {
                    Create();
                }


            }

        }
    }

private void BindDropDownLists()
     {
         column_list_for_filter.ConnectionString = connection;
         column_list_for_filter.SelectCommand = "SELECT DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE))as DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'RESULT' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'))";
         DropDownList5.DataTextField = "COLUMN_NAME";
         DropDownList5.DataValueField = "DATA_TYPE";
         DropDownList5.DataBind();

     }
```